# Chrome 52's Built In Cast Option is not appearing

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

Chrome 51 and up now has [built-in casting capability](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6398952?hl=en-CA). Unfortunately, it is not appearing for me. Here is what my version of Chrome says is its version number:

[image]

I have a Nexus Player on the same network which I've used to chrome cast for many months. It works very reliably. Everything, like YouTube, Google Photos and other computers with an old Chrome browser + Google Cast extension, can connect to it *except* this Chrome browser. The option simply doesn't show up:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what may be wrong or a suggestion on how to resolve?

Comment: I have the same version of Chrome, except on Linux... not showing up for me either. The standard extension I've always used still works though.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually enable it under "Media Router" in Chrome's flags: **chrome://flags/#media-router**

It doesn't show up for me either, so I can't tell you why, but after manually enabling it, the casting works fine.

Comment: Much appreciated. Worked perfectly for me; Chrome  55.0.2883.28 beta (64-bit), running under Ubuntu 14.04.